# Android Studio: Background Image causing Lag

Tags: android

I am new to android studio, and was learning how to use it.
I've encountered a slight graphic issue which is the lag when a HorizontalScrollView items being scrolled. I've used a FrameLayout and put an ImageView as the background of the Horizontal View. I used ImageView as my background because I want to to change it later.

Please tell me if there is another method of putting a background Image without causing lag when items are being scrolled.

Thank you!

[image]